# Bootstrap collapse - opening multiple accordions at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got to a point where my accordions open up at the same time - see http://www.bootply.com/Go4t29rYyF

When you click on "tab1" all the "tab1s" open, when you click on "tab2" all the "tab2s" open - great! But I cant open "tab1s & tab2s" at the same time, it only works when I close one of the tabs first before opening another. The issue is with my js but cant work it out.

```
$(function () {

        var $active = true;

        $('.panel-title > a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('.number1-collapse').on('click', function () {
            if (!$active) {
                $active = true;
                $('.panel-title > a').attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
                $('.number1').collapse('hide');
            } else {
                $active = false;
                $('.number1').collapse('show');
                $('.panel-title > a').attr('data-toggle', '');
            }
        });


        $('.number2-collapse').on('click', function () {
            if (!$active) {
                $active = true;
                $('.panel-title > a').attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
                $('.number2').collapse('hide');
            } else {
                $active = false;
                $('.number2').collapse('show');
                $('.panel-title > a').attr('data-toggle', '');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tidied up your code and changed to using the `toggle` method instead of having various flags. The problem is that you are sharing the active flag between them. Here is the improved code and [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/dcRbezDw3F#):

```
$(function () {
    $('.panel-title > a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.number1-collapse').on('click', function () {
        $('.number1').collapse('toggle');
    });

    $('.number2-collapse').on('click', function () {
        $('.number2').collapse('toggle');
    });
});
```

Comment: That seemed really simple - here's to over complicating things!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to specify which elements you are effecting in your function using the event parameter

Example:

```
   $('.number2-collapse').on('click', function (event) {
        var panelTitle = $(event.currentTarget).find('.panel-title > a');
        var number = $(event.currentTarget).find('.number2');
        if (!$active) {
            $active = true;
            $(panelTitle).attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
            $(number).collapse('hide');
        } else {
            $active = false;
            $(number).collapse('show');
            $(panelTitle).attr('data-toggle', '');
        }
    });
```

> This is an example. **You may need to alter this code for it to work in your situation**